# .NET Core parâmetro JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

Eu estou começando a aprender C#, usando .NET CORE, e estou tentando criar uma API que realiza buscas em um banco MongoDB.

Já procurei em alguns tópicos aqui, vi algumas coisas, mas nenhuma das soluções que encontrei funcionou.

Eu criei uma classe chamada SearchParameter para poder receber os parâmetros de busca, porém quando tento realizar a mesma no Insominia ele retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo entender o que está havendo. Seguem as classes.

SearchParametrs:

```
public class SearchParameters
{
    // Propriedes

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É necessário informar um parâmetro de busca.")]
    [JsonProperty("ticketField")]
    public string ticketField { get; set; } // representa o campo do ticket que será utilizado para busca.

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É necessário informar um parâmetro de comparação.")]
    [JsonProperty("comparationParameter")]
    public string comparationParameter { get; set; } // representa o parâmetro de comparação, se o valor a ser buscado é IGUAL ou DIFERENTE do ticketField.

    [JsonProperty("initialDate")]
    public DateTime initialDate { get; set; } // representa a data incial de um período a ser pequisado.

    [JsonProperty("finalDate")]
    public DateTime finalDate { get; set; } // representa a data final de um período a ser pesquisado. 
}
```

Inicio do CONTROLLER, que define a rota:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("v1/archivedTickets")]
public class ArchivedTicketsController : ControllerBase
{...}
```

Método GET do CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("getByChannelName/{searchParameters}")]
    public IActionResult getByChannelName(SearchParameters searchParameters)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_repository.GetByChannelName(searchParameters));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Método que realiza a busca no REPOSITÓRIO:

```
public List<ArchivedTicketsModel> GetByChannelName(SearchParameters searchParameters)
    {
        return _collection.Find(archivedTicket => archivedTicket.ChannelName == searchParameters.ticketField && archivedTicket.DateCreation >= searchParameters.initialDate && archivedTicket.DateCreation <= searchParameters.finalDate).ToList();
        
    }
```

Eu coloquei um breakpoint na classe do CONTROLLER para debugar, mas o Insominia retorna essa mensagem sem nem ao menos entrar no método GET.

Estou testando em um localhost, que é a minha base_url. Já tem receber os parâmetros de forma separada, e deu certo, mas o objeto JSON não vai, e eu quero receber esse objeto como parâmetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você define a sua rota dessa forma

```
[Route("getByChannelName/{searchParameters}")]
```

O seu método está esperando receber um parâmetro único.

Você definiu o seu método como HTTP/GET, por padrão ele não verifica o que está no corpo da requisição para preencher sua classe de parâmetro.
O que você pode fazer é informa-lo que você está esperando um objeto que está no body.

```
public IActionResult getByChannelName([Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromBody]SearchParameters searchParameters)
```

Dessa forma, não é necessário passar na rota, ficando apenas

```
[Route("getByChannelName")]
```

Comment: Deu certinho! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!